# How to make QtCreator FakeVim replace TABS by SPACES on file save?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, fakevim

QtCreator editor can replace TABS by SPACES on file save which I think is an awesome feature. But FakeVim is even more awesome, the only problem is that FakeVim doesn't seem to replace TABS by SPACES on file.

How to make QtCreator FakeVim replace TABS by SPACES on file save?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the command *:retab* is not known by FakeVim.

So I solved it this way:

```
:%s/\t/    /g
```

This has to be done before saving the file.

BR Guenther